# Android variable modified in method doesn't update in thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, canvas, scope

I have a simple application that displays an image on the screen via a SurfaceView nested in an activity layout.

I have a SurfaceViewExample class that creates a new instance of OurView, and contains the methods that are called by the buttons. There are three methods:

1. The first method is arrowPressed(View view), which is called when any of the three arrow keys is pressed. It gets the id of which button called it and passes that to
2. arrowAction(OurView ourview, String direction) which calls
3. moveImage(int xChange, int yChange) with the x and y changes necessary to move the image in that direction.

   ```
   public void arrowPressed(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {

           case R.id.arrowLeft:
               arrowAction(gameView, "left");
               break;

           case R.id.arrowRight:
               arrowAction(gameView, "right");
               break;

           case R.id.arrowUp:
               arrowAction(gameView, "up");
               break;
       }
   }

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   void arrowAction(OurView ourView, String direction) {
       switch (direction) {

           case "left":
               ourView.moveImage(-1,0);
               break;

           case "right":
               ourView.moveImage(1,0);
               break;

           case "up":
               ourView.moveImage(0,1);
               break;
       }
   }

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   void moveImage(int xChange, int yChange) {
       xCoord = xCoord + xChange;
       yCoord = yCoord + yChange;
   }
   ```

This all seems to work as intended. moveImage is successfully called, and it modifies the xCoord and yCoord variables. When I print the x and y Coords from within moveImage, they reflect their changed values. However, there seems to be a disconnect between the xCoord and yCoord in moveImage, and the xCoord and yCoord in the thread MyThread.

The method doDraw(Canvas canvas) draws a bitmap at (xPos, yPos) (these variables are just adjusted x and y Coords so that the image is centered on that coordinate point, rather than having it's top left corner be on that coordinate point). When I print the x and y Coords from this method, they reflect the original values.

```
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    xPos = xCoord - (testimg.getWidth()/2);
    yPos = yCoord - (testimg.getHeight()/2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(testimg, xPos, yPos, null);
}
```

The only reason I can think of this happening is that moveImage is creating new local variables called xCoord and yCoord. However that doesn't make sense because it successfully gets the original value of xCoord and yCoord.

Full code:

SurfaceViewExample:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity {

    OurView gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new OurView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_surface_view_example);
    }

    public void arrowPressed(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.arrowLeft:
                arrowAction(gameView, "left");
                break;

            case R.id.arrowRight:
                arrowAction(gameView, "right");
                break;

            case R.id.arrowUp:
                arrowAction(gameView, "up");
                break;
        }
    }

    void arrowAction(OurView ourView, String direction) {
        switch (direction) {

            case "left":
                ourView.moveImage(-1,0);
                break;

            case "right":
                ourView.moveImage(1,0);
                break;

            case "up":
                ourView.moveImage(0,1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

OurView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MyThread myThread;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Bitmap testimg;
    public int xCoord = 500;
    public int yCoord = 500;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OurView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OurView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        myThread = new MyThread(this);

        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        testimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.testimg);
    }

    void moveImage(int xChange, int yChange) {
        xCoord = xCoord + xChange;
        yCoord = yCoord + yChange;
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println(xCoord);
        System.out.println(yCoord);
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("-----");
    }

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        System.out.println("Starting drawing...");
        System.out.println(xCoord);
        System.out.println(yCoord);
        xPos = xCoord - (testimg.getWidth()/2);
        yPos = yCoord - (testimg.getHeight()/2);
        System.out.println(xPos);
        System.out.println(yPos);
        canvas.drawBitmap(testimg, xPos, yPos, null);
        System.out.println("Drawing finished.");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        myThread.setRunning(true);
        myThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry =  true;
        myThread.setRunning(false);

        while (retry) {
            try {
                myThread.join();
                retry = false;
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

}
```

MyThread:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class MyThread extends Thread{

    OurView myView;
    private boolean running = false;

    public MyThread(OurView view) {
        myView = view;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running){

            Canvas canvas = myView.getHolder().lockCanvas();

            if(canvas != null){
                synchronized (myView.getHolder()) {
                    myView.doDraw(canvas);
                }
                myView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            try {
                sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The MyThread class was almost pure copy+paste from [Create animation on SurfaceView in background Thread](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/03/create-animation-on-surfaceview-in.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canvas object form MyThread is changed each time onDraw is called. You should not reference Canvas in other classes.

Comment: What are the alternatives to referencing the canvas from MyThread?

Comment: Use the main thread for rendering and draw the object in onDraw method referencing the needed objects in OurView class.